# Extract the word between the quotes and store the values in an variable

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I need to extract the word between the quotes and store the values in an variable.

my actural string will be

> m:'liquid' n:'4'

from the above string. I need to extract

the word `liquid` & `4`

and to store like this

```
var m = "liquid";
var n = "4";
```

How can I do this in regular expression in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic solution

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetValues(string input)
{
    var results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var pairs = input.Split(" ");
    foreach(var pair in pairs)
    {
        var parts = pair.Split(":");
        results.Add(parts[0], parts[1].Trim("'"));
    }
    return results;
}

var str = "m:'liquid' n:'4'";
var values = GetValues(str);
var m = values["m"];
var n = values["n"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Well if the format is always that, then you can split by `:` and know that you will have an array of strings that start with the element you want, between `'` chars.

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged your question with a "linq", you can try this:

```
var str = @"m:'liquid' n:'4'";
var r = str.Split(new [] {'\''}).Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 1).ToArray();
var m = r[0];
var n = r[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=')\\w+(?<!')");
var matches = regex.Matches("m:'liquid' n:'4'");
```

Will match any word preceeded by ' and followed by '.

```
var m = matches[0];
var n = matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var s = "m:'liquid' n:'4'";
   var ss = s.Split(new char[]{' ', ':'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You will have the pairs in ss: {"m", "'liquid'", "n", "'4'"}. It works if there is empty value ('').

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the .[indexOf](http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof) string

```
var x = "m:'liquid' n:'4'";
var split = x.Split(' ');
var indexm0 = split[0].IndexOf("'");
var indexm1 = split[0].LastIndexOf("'");

var m = split[0].Substring(indexm0, indexm1 - 1);

var indexn0 = split[1].IndexOf("'");
var indexn1 = split[1].LastIndexOf("'");
var n = split[1].Substring(indexn0, indexn1 - 1);
```

Comment: -1 if he already knows the value is "liquid" or "4" there isn't any point of extracting it from the string.

Comment: @juharr then if you  dont mind. what is your opinion or understanding in the accepted answer or and other answer?.

Comment: My opinion of the accepted answer is that it will work for the specific case mentioned here along with other possibilities, making it a much more flexible solution.

Comment: in my updated answer.. what is your understanding for this Mr. @juharr?